# Ubuntu 18.04 mounting buffalo linkstation always with parse error in fstab

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

```
$ cat /etc/fstab

gUID=b8e93e66-9575-44f9-8ef5-97665713b7e3 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
//192.168.1.103/share /mnt/Media cifs username=guest,uid=1000 g g
```

Hi all

I am trying to mount a Buffalo Linkstation on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM.
The above is my /etc/fstab, but whenever I run `sudo mount -a` I get `parse error at line 4 -- ignored`.
I followed the instruction on this webpage: https://mginternet.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/mounting-a-buffalo-linkstation-share-on-ubuntu/

and it seemed pretty correct. The linkstation does have the share folder and I can access it on windows just fine.

The IP address is reachable from my VM as well via ping.

I am at a loss as to what could have caused this.

Comment: I see two typos on line 4.

Comment: lol ok what is it because I am not seeing them. the share is there, the Media is correctly spelled, the rest is copy pasted and doesn't seem to be spelled wrong

Comment: Look harder. Compare the line in the the instructions with your fstab line 4, char by char.

Comment: Your line ends with `g g` instead of `0 0`. Surely that would cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have a ls220de. Maybe this can help you, This is my config:

```
//192.168.0.XXX/share /mnt/z cifs username=admin,password=ThePassword,vers=1.0,auto,x-systemd.automount,uid=1000,guid=1000
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//192.168.0.XXX/share /mnt/z cifs username=admin,password=ThePassword,vers=1.0,auto,x-systemd.automount,uid=1000,guid=1000
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

The key point is the option **vers=1.0**

If you see dmesg, you can see that this is recommended (at least in my case)